# Iron PDF: Print html table with lots of columns

Tags: css, pdf, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, ironpdf

I'm using iron odf to print that table. But it prints only the left part of the table, and the right part it won't print. Is there a way to print the table on multiple pages?

As pictured bewlo the generated PDF does not include all the columns in my table and it is cut off at the city column.
None of my remaining columns are are in page 2 either. I want the the remaining columns to move to page 2 on need basis. Note that : Making the page fitted is not an option for me.

All I want is to move columns that do not fit to move to page two instead of being ignored.

Below is my code

```
 var renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
 var html= @"<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <body>
                    <h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>
                    <table style='width:100% ; border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse; '>
                      <tr style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Firstname</th>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Lastname</th> 
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Age</th>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Profession</th>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>address line 1</th>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>address line 2</th>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>phone</th>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>zipcode</th>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>state</th>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>City</th>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Notes</th>
                        <th style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Medical History</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Jill</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Smith</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>50</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Software Developer</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>8763 W Amsterdam  ave</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Unit 1 A</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>00291-7-12-12-99</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>60987</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>IL</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Chicago</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>He  is a very hard working person and needs to be treated properly</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Allergy to Medications none, Diabetic type 1</td>
                      </tr>  
                      <tr style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Amete</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Jackson</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>26</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Jr Application Developer</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>1234 N ASmara  ave</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Unit 7A</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>00291-7-14-98-99</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>60543</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>IL</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Chicago</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Very energetic eager to learn new field</td>
                        <td style=' border: 1px solid black ; border-collapse: collapse '>Allergy to Medications none, N=o known disease</td>
                      </tr>  
                    </table>
                    </body>
                    </html>";

            _pdfDoc = renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(html);
  
            _pdfDoc.SaveAs("Employees.pdf");
```

[image: Below Generated PDF with columns cut]

Comment: @KJ I am using Iron PDf that is generated from html.

Comment: @KJ but I need the code using iron pdf to generate the pdf you showed above.

Comment: My problem is the missing columns in second page and How to make my html table in two or more pages based in column length using iron pdf.